# Approaches to route request to relevant services in Microservices Architecture

Tags: tomcat, microservices

Suppose we are having 5 services (Users and Authorisation, Product, Orders, Inventory, History) exposing REST based API and communicate internally between services via these exposed API's only. Now while developing this in a Microeservice Architectural pattern these will be different individual services which will be self reliant and communicate to each other via REST/Queues.

To start of with lets consider we are deploying this on a single node as of now where all the 5 services are deployed on this single node only. So one approach is

1. **(Ideal)** To have a Service Discovery and Registry Mechanism via Netflix tool chain (eureka) or via Zookeper to direct the request to relevant services after authentication and authorization e.g /api/v1/Products/{id} to be directed to Products services , /api/v1/order/{id} to be directed to Order services and so on.
2. **Another one** (though not the right one for the scenario where the services are distributed on multiple nodes , but considering if we are having all the services on a single node and plan to go live quickly and then in next phases go towards Discovery/Registry , API gateway, circuit breaker approach of Microservices) in which we develop all the services as separate web apps deployed as individual war in tomcat (Spring based app) and let tomcat to handle the redirection on basis of URL e.g https://ip:port/**productservice**/api/v1/products/{id} redirected by tomcat to **productservice** webapp and so on.

Will the **option 2** will be a viable option to go live with different services developed as a separate webapp , self reliant with it's own schema deployed in a single tomcat instance and being consumed from UI layer and then in next phases use this base code of individual and separate service and go towards discovery/registry approach.

But the challenge i was foreseeing in **Option 2** where each service is a separate war (without discovery/registry) is the ***routing***  - as main entry for each request e.g https://ip:port/**productservice**/api/v1/products/{id} before going to **productservice** webapp need to go through a "authentication service" app and then to be routed to appropriate service and handling this routing in a separate war mechanism (though on a single instance) have following option

1. each request needs to landed on to the authentication service app (how ? can be URL redirection) and then some routing logic is written to send the authenticated request to the required app(service) which is REST based. This routing can be a camel based or simply DB based -  parsing the string and calling the REST API of the required service . The authentication app will then act as an API gateway.
2. Other is the one which you mentioned (missing of queues). All request lands on to the authentication service app (how ? can be URL redirection) and then this writes to individual queue dedicated to each service , where each service subscribes to it specific queue.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2, so running all separate webapps on a single tomcat instance per node is a very good first step toward full-blown microservices architecture. In fact you anyway need this step to implement service discovery/registry later. As you write - it will already give you some level of isolation and ability to perform independent migrations (with separate wars).

Just make sure you wrap the code for getting services URL into a class, so that you will make changes in one place only when adding Service Discovery (vs hardcoding URLs for services in multiple places in your app).

Cons of stopping for some time on option 2 is that you will lose ability to scale on a per-service level. You will need to answer the question how critical it is in your specific scenario.

What I don't see in your post is your approach for using queues. Honestly, if your solution can use asynchronous communication, I would strongly encourage it (note that Netflix stack is predominantly targeted at direct REST communication).

Comment: Agree with you , updated the post with the challenge i foresee in separate app without service discovery is how to route to appropriate service after every request is authenticated via "authentication service" app